# Artistic License 2.0 пояснение для пункта 13

Tags: лицензирование, авторские-права, artistic-license

В тексте лицензии [Artistic License 2.0](https://opensource.org/licenses/Artistic-2.0) имеется следующий пункт под номером 13:

> (13) This license includes the non-exclusive, worldwide,
>   free-of-charge patent license to make, have made, use, offer to sell,
>   sell, import and otherwise transfer the Package with respect to any
>   patent claims licensable by the Copyright Holder that are necessarily
>   infringed by the Package. If you institute patent litigation
>   (including a cross-claim or counterclaim) against any party alleging
>   that the Package constitutes direct or contributory patent
>   infringement, then this Artistic License to you shall terminate on the
>   date that such litigation is filed.

И с пониманием этого пункта возникли сложности. Объясните как его следует правильно понимать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала перевод:

> (13) Эта лицензия включает неисключительную, всемирную, бесплатную
>   патентную лицензию на сборку, внедрение, использование, предложение на
>   продажу, продажу, импортирование и другую передачу Пакета по отношению
>   к любым пунктам патента, лицензируемых владельцем авторских прав,
>   которые обязательно нарушаются Пакетом. Если вы начинаете тяжбу в
>   отношении любой стороны, утверждая, что Пакет является прямым
>   патентным нарушением или способствует оному, то в таком случае
>   данная Artistic License по отношению к Вам прекратит своё действия на
>   дату регистрации данного иска.

Первое предложение говорит о том, что владелец авторских прав выдаёт вам бесплатное право на использование и продажу Пакета, как-бы в ущерб своих авторских прав, попросту говоря делится с вами.

Второе предложение предупреждает о том, что если вы начнёте иск в отношение кого-либо по поводу нарушения чьих-либо патентных прав данным Пакетом, прямого или косвенного, то вы лишаетесь всех тех прав, которые предоставляется данной лицензией. Т.е. не плюй в колодец из которого пьёшь.

P.S. Перевод и трактовка вольные, замечания и уточнения приветствуются.